# SQL Concat and merge values

Tags: sql

How to make it correct, whats wrong with this?

```
SELECT Name, Surname, CONCAT(NAME + ' '+ SURNAME) 'name and surname'
FROM Worker
WHERE Born = '1988';
```

or

```
SELECT Name, Surname, 'NAME' + ' '+ 'SURNAME' AS 'name and surname'
FROM Worker
WHERE Born = '1988';
```

Comment: Please edit & add a tag specifying the specific database platform are you using as well as any error messages you encounter.

Comment: None of them are correct, according to the <sql> tag (which is for ANSI SQL.)

Comment: I guess,something in between SELECT Name, Surname, NAME + ' '+ SURNAME AS "name and surname"
FROM Worker
WHERE Born = '1988';

Answer (score 2):

The standard SQL operator for concatenation is `||`, so you want:

```
SELECT Name, Surname, (NAME || ' ' || SURNAME) as full_name
FROM Worker
WHERE Born = '1988';
```

Many databases also support a `CONCAT()` function, although logically you want at least two arguments.  SQL Server uses `+` for string concatenation, but that is not widespread.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong in the two queries:

```
SELECT Name, Surname, CONCAT(NAME, ' ', SURNAME) "name and surname"
FROM Worker
WHERE Born = '1988';
```

or

```
SELECT Name, Surname, NAME + ' '+ SURNAME AS "name and surname"
FROM Worker
WHERE Born = '1988';
```

Suposing you are using Microsoft SQL Server, keep in mind there are actually few differences between regular `+` operator and `concat()` function.

1. `concat()` will implicitly converts any parameter to a string while `+` will throw an error if you mix strings and other types
2. `concat()` will always return a `not null` string even if all parameters are null. `+` will return `null` as soon as any column is `null`.